# Calculating Margin Of Error

Tags: statistics

I'm having trouble calculating the margin of error for this problem.

"What is the overall margin of error of the survey, at 95% confidence, if it is based on a simple random sample of 1111 voters?"

I got this far:

1-(95/100) = 0.05
1-0.05/2 = 0.975 critical probability
1111-1 = 1110 degrees of freedom
1.962t score

And then I have no idea what to do next.

Comment: Margin of error = Critical value x Standard error of the statistic

Comment: Who or what do the voters vote ? Are there 2 canditates/options for choice ? What are the probabilities for a single vote?

Comment: "A survey is being conducted on voters' opinion on several different issues." That's all the information given before part 1, which is fully written in the OP.

Comment: Because $n (=1,111)$ is large  $t_{0.975}$ can be approximated by $z_{0.975}$ (standard normal distribution). $\Phi^{-1}(0.975)=1.96$. Thus the margin of error is $1.96\cdot \frac{s}{\sqrt{1111}}$. s is the estimated standard deviation.

Comment: It the is no further Information, why did you apply the t-distribution ?

Comment: If my answer resolves your question, then please click to Accept the answer, and the question will drop off our list of ones without helpful answers. If not, please leave a comment asking for clarification and I (or someone else) will probably be able to help.

Answer (score 1):

The margin of error of a public opinion poll (95% confidence) is
$1.96\sqrt{\hat p(1-\hat p)/n}.$ Where $n = 1111$ and $\hat p = X/n$ is the ratio of the number $X$ of people favoring a particular position
to the number $n$ of people interviewed (and the estimate of the
population proportion $p$ holding that opinion).

Your difficulty is that you do not know $X$ so you can't find $\hat p.$
However, the largest possible product $\hat p(1-\hat p)$ occurs
when $\hat p = 1/2.$ Hence, the largest possible margin of
error is 
$$1.96\sqrt{1/4n} \approx 1/\sqrt{n} = 1/\sqrt{1111} = 0.03.$$

To see that the largest value is at 1/2, consider the graph of the ("upside down") parabola with equation $y = x(1-x);$ it reaches
its maximum value 1/4 at $x = 1/2.$

Actually, $\hat p$ needs to be fairly far from 1/2 before
$\hat p(1-\hat p)$ is far from 1/4. Consider, a 60:40
split in opinion gives $.6(.4) = .24$, and even a 70:30 split
gives $.21.$

Most polling organizations quote this $1/\sqrt{n}$ margin of
error even when it is somewhat too large (possibly acknowledging that
errors not accounted for in the simple binomial model are
also present).

*Note:* The number $1.96$ is based on the normal approximation
to the binomial. The numbers $\pm 1.96$ cut 2.5% from the lower
and upper tails of a standard normal distribution, leaving
95% of the probability in the center. Student's t distribution
is not involved here.