# Calculating required sample size given X outcomes (empirical measurements)

Tags: statistics, sampling

I am doing some testing on a game to try and establish whether the outcomes from various mini-game mechanics match their advertised odds.

#### Here are a few examples

1. **Rolling two dice (presumed 'fair' dice)**
   36 total outcomes with equal distribution, 11 equivalent outcomes
2. **Spinning a 10-segment wheel (presumed fair, i.e. odds of each segment being 1/10)**
   10 outcomes with equal distribution
3. **Drawing a card with 1 of 3 outcomes (odds of each being: 3/6, 2/6 and 1/6 respectively)**
   3 outcomes with un-even distribution, lowest common denominator of 1/6th

#### How many samples are 'enough'

I am trying to understand how many samples I need to gather for each mechanic (and some others not mentioned) in order to say the results are within "X% margin for error"

**Please can someone advise if there is a formula something along the lines of...

`O [number of outcomes] ÷ N [sample size] * X [some value of equation] = margin for error`**

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

---

#### Research attempted / knowledge used

- I did stats in school but that was admittedly many years ago now. I know there are terms like 'margin for error' and 'confidence interval' - I think the former is what I'm after(?)
- As part of my googling I read about `p-` and `z-` scores but don't really understand these or how to calculate them
- I looked through: [Calculating Margin Of Error](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1301474/calculating-margin-of-error) but this was *way* above my level of understanding
- I looked through: [Correlation between margin of error and sample size](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4238597/correlation-between-margin-of-error-and-sample-size), but this (and other pages I read) talked about a mean value - however that doesn't apply to my data/intended calculation (AFAIK).